# move collection view chats up when inputAccessoryView appears

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, chat, inputaccessoryview

I am working with chat screens where I have a `InputAccessoryView` where user type message and `UICollectionView` which contains chats.
I want to display latest chat message when user send it in UICollectionView.
Problem is when user types message InputAccessoryView comes up to a keyboard and UICollectionView goes behind to Keyboard so latest messages are not visible.
I want to move UICollectionView up to keyboard height when keyboard appears.

I am using following code.

This will register observer for keyboard hide and show events.

```
func handleKeyBoard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }


@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            var contentInset = self.collectionView?.contentInset
            contentInset?.bottom = keyboardSize.height
            self.collectionView?.contentInset = contentInset!
            if self.messages.count > 0{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                }, completion: { (completed:Bool) in
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                })

            }
        }
    }
```

In above function when keyboard appears I am getting it's height which always comes as 50 I don't know why may be because of `InputAccessoryView`.
After getting keyboard height I am adding 50 more as a height for `InputAccessoryView` and then changing the `contentInset` of a `UICollectionViewController` and in the completion of animation I am scrolling to a last message which will scroll UICollectionViewController to it's last message.

But it is not happening.

This is my default `contentInset` for UICollectionView.

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)
```

after

```
var contentInset = self.collectionView?.contentInset
                contentInset?.bottom = keyboardSize.height
                self.collectionView?.contentInset = contentInset!
```

contentInset becomes this.

```
UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)
```

Following will set defaul Inset for collectionview once keyboard hides

```
 @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
              self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                }, completion: { (completed:Bool) in

                })
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me to find right approach to do this. That will be very helpful.
Almost all chatting app have this feature where when they type then can see a new message in there chat view.

Thank You.

Comment: libraries like - IQKeyboardManager can be used to handle such problems

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to add constrains to collectionView and InputAccessoryView such that bottomview of collectionview is attached to accessory view and accessory view to bottom of super view. 
[image]
[image]

Next Make the outlet of bottom space constrain in you .m file and call is   scrollViewBottomSpace and add the following code. 
Constrain will do the work for you.

#pragma mark - Key board notifications

```
- (void)addObservers
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)removeObservers
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Keyboard notification handlers

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if(_keyboardIsVisible) return;

    CGFloat height = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        scrollViewBottomSpace.constant = height+40;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

    _keyboardIsVisible = YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if(!_keyboardIsVisible) return;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        scrollViewBottomSpace.constant = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

    _keyboardIsVisible = NO;
}
```

Comment: I am not using any storyboards. Also I am using `UICollectionViewControll` so the constraints for  `UICollectionView` is sets by default. And for `InputAccessoryView`   also I have not set any constraints it appears as it is by default. `self.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight` i have set only this property into the view of `InputAccessoryView` which adjust it's height base on content inside it.

Comment: when first time chat screen appears keyboardWillShow method calls automatically and that time I am getting actual keyboard height. But after that when I click in `inputAccessoryView` to type message and keyboard appears it gives height of 50 which is same as `inputAccessoryView` height. That means I am not getting actual height of keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple, if you are using `UICollectionViewController` you don't need to manage the `contentInset` by your self just let the `CollectionViewController` handle it by it self, all you have to is to scroll down when your 'textView' or 'textField' becomes first responder or when you send a message

To scroll `collectionView` down you just use this function

```
func scrollToBottom() {
    let numberOfSections = self.collectionView!.numberOfSections
    if numberOfSections > 0 {
        let numberOfRows = self.collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: numberOfSections - 1)
        if numberOfRows > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows-1, section: (numberOfSections-1))
            self.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)` this two lines doing the same what you suggested.

Comment: First line gets the last item index and the second line scrolls to that line a bottom alignment so that you the cells on top of inputAccessoryView, I didn't understand what you want to know ?

Comment: Hello @Amr the problem was  `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` because of this i was not getting actual height of keyboard. Instead of that I used this  `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` and now I am able to get height of keyboard.The remaining problem was that when `KeyboardWillHide` method was getting called it automatically calls the `KeyboardWillShow` but at this time in `KeyboardWillShow` method the height of keyboard was 50 not the actual height.

Comment: so I add a constraint if height is more than 50 then change the `UICollectionViewInsets`  here is the solution I posted. [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355483/input-accessory-view-behave-unexpectedly-with-keyboard-hide-and-show-events?noredirect=1#comment89684874_51355483)

Answer (score 0):

At this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355483/input-accessory-view-behave-unexpectedly-with-keyboard-hide-and-show-events?noredirect=1#comment89684874_51355483) I have answer this question the problem was with `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` instead of that I used `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`