# Input Accessory View Behave Unexpectedly with keyboard hide and show events

Tags: swift, keyboard-events, inputaccessoryview

I am facing an strange behavior with InputAccessoryView, I am working on chat screen where I have used `InputAccessoryView` where I have registered for `KeyboardWillShow`   and `KeyboardWillHide` notifications. When my chat screen appears it automatically calls the `KeyboardWillShowMethod` once and after that it hides automatically without calling the `KeyboardWillHide` notification. After Loading chats when I click on textbox to type text it calls `KeyboardWillShow` which is fine. But when I try to hide keybaord it calls two methods first it will call `KeyboardWillHide` and after that it will call `KeyboardWillShow` which is strange.

This is my chat screen [Image](https://ibb.co/c6326y) when keyboard is hidden.
This is when keyboard is shown [Image](https://ibb.co/ney26y)

I am using this `InputAccessoryView` Code Programatically [inputAccessoryView](https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView)

This is how I have registered for keyboard notifications.

```
  func handleKeyBoard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            var contentInset = self.collectionView?.contentInset
            contentInset?.bottom = keyboardSize.maxY
            self.collectionView?.contentInset = contentInset!
            self.collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset!
          //  collectionViewBottomAnchor?.constant = keyboardSize.height + 50

//            print ("input height  \(inputAccessoryView?.frame.maxY) ")
//            print("keyboard height \(keyboardSize.height)")
//            print("keyboard Y \(keyboardSize.maxY)")
//            print("keyboard Y \(keyboardSize.minY)")
            //print("keyboard Y \(inputAccessoryView.framemaxY)")


            if self.messages.count > 0{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                }, completion: { (completed:Bool) in
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

                })
            }
        }
    }

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            print("keyboard hide")
          self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)

            self.collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: { (completed:Bool) in

            })
        }
    }
```

In selectors I am trying to change my `CollectionView` Insets according to a Y Index of Keyboard because I am not getting Height of keybaord that is also an issue. Height of kyeboard is always 50 as of height of inputAccessoryView.

Comment: Show your selector code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri  I have updated the questions with selector methods.

Comment: Instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` try using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey `.

Comment: Also check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286239/iphone-x-keyboard-appear-showing-extra-space if it helps in your scenario.

Comment: Hey @Amit thank you. it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I have found Thanx to @Amit. Instead of using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` I have used `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` after doing this I was able to get accurate hight of keyboard in `KeyboardWillAppear` method. Now the problem which remains was that `KeyboardWillShow` method was get called after `KeyboardWillHide` but at that time the `KeyboardWillShow` have a hight of keyboard 50.
That means when i try to hide a keyboard it will call KeyboardWillHide which is fine and after that It automatically calls `KeyboardWillShow` but height of keyboard remains 50 so I put condition there.

Now following method will make effect only when height is more than 50.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        if keyboardSize.height > 50{
                var contentInset = self.collectionView?.contentInset
                contentInset?.bottom = keyboardSize.height + 50
                self.collectionView?.contentInset = contentInset!
                self.collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset!


            if self.messages.count > 0{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                }, completion: { (completed:Bool) in
                                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                                        self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

                })
            }
        }

    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)
            self.collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 52, right: 0)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: { (completed:Bool) in

            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**When keyboard has input accessory view, `keyboardDidHideNotification` is observed twice:**

1. When keyboard is hidden.
2. When input accessroy view is hidden (note that input accessory view is visible for a while after keyboard is dismissed).

If your implementation depends on selector to be called just once, you can do one of following workarounds:

**Option A: Check keyboard frame:**

```
@objc
private func keyboardDidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardRect = notification.keyboardRect, keyboardRect.origin.y == view.frame.maxY else {
        return
    }
    // Do whatever you need...
}
```

```
extension Notification {
    var keyboardRect: CGRect? {
        guard let keyboardSize = userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
            return nil
        }
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue
    }
}
```

**Option B: Throttle reaction using GDC:**

```
private var pendingKeyboardDidHideRequestWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?

private func keyboardDidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    pendingKeyboardDidHideRequestWorkItem?.cancel()

    let keyboardDidHideRequestWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
        // Do whatever you need...
    }

    pendingKeyboardDidHideRequestWorkItem = keyboardDidHideRequestWorkItem
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500), execute: keyboardDidHideRequestWorkItem)
}
```